# For how long afterwards can you publish papers based on field research?

Tags: publications, independent-researcher, anthropology

In 2010 I did field research for my Masters Thesis in International Peace & Conflict Resolution (i.e. multi-disciplinary social science and international relations) in Bolivia interviewing indigenous judges. The interviews focused on the structure & function of their indigenous judicial system and its relationship of the state system. After graduation, I had wanted to publish a version of my thesis but never got around to it. After a while, I assumed too many years had passed for any of it to still be relevant to publish but then I was reading an anthropology methodology book that mentioned how anthropologists will publish papers based on notes from field work for years after finishing the field work.

I still have all my notes and recorded interviews. Could I still publish a paper in a journal based on 10 year old field research?

(Note: I haven't decided on a specific social science field I'd want to publish but does it make a difference? I am also not a academic associated with any university.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prove a theory or find an interesting or useful relationship using 100 year-old data you can publish, that is send to a journal for review.

It is not the age of the data but the results / analysis / conclusions.